# how does asset precompile work when using different output formats (html and mobile)?

Tags: jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, passenger

My app has twio different user interfaces, one called when invoked by a standard browser on a PC and a different one when invoked by a mobile device.
So in my assets directory I have

```
assets
  javascripts
    application.js
    mobile
      application.js
  stylesheets
    application.css
    mobile
      application.css
      mobileapp.css

....
....

views
  layouts
    application.html.erb
    application.mobile.erb
```

manifest files are:

**javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_directory .
```

**javascripts/mobile/application.js**

```
//= require jquery.mobile
//= require_directory .
```

**stylesheets/application.css**

```
*= require_self
*= require_directory .
*/
```

**stylesheets/mobile/application.css**

```
*= require jquery.mobile
*= require_directory .
*/
```

All works ok in development, BUT...
as soon as I go to production mode (Apache/Passenger) when I invoke the app with a mobile device I see that the mobile application layout is used, but syles contained in mobile/mobileapp.css are not used.

I have no way to debug on mobile devices (no firebug or google chrome developer tools).
Is there any way to know what is being served by passenger to the mobile device? I know, I can always use wireshark to sniff network packets, but should it exist some higher level tool I'd be grateful..

**EDIT**

Maybe now I've figured out what is causing the problem.
I know that jquery mobile does its "magic"just after the DOM is loaded.
When the app is served by passenger (after precompiling assets) to a mobile device,
the correct page and the correct application layout are served, but Jquery mobile does not initialize all its elements at DOM load, so my pages remain in a "hybrid" state.

Anyone who had this kind of problem and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not the first time that I ask a question and then I also post an answer, having not received any answer yet...

To capture the HTML code of the page i would receive on a mobile device without having tools like Firebug for mobile platform I simply launch from command line the following:

```
curl -A android http://www.mysite.com/mypage
```

I use the ability of cURL to send an http request where I control the user-agent that is being sent. 
Not like having Firebug but now I know whichj HTML is actually sent to the mobile device.